# Facebook Chat messenger Schema

Tags: database-design, system

I was asked the question in an interview to Design the Facebook chat messenger.
The requirements were it should be able to support the one to one conversation and it should be real time.
  While discussing the schema regarding how am i going to store the conversation between two users so that i do not have to load the whole conversation and then create the view that i am going to shown in the chat box.
  Can anybody tell me the elaborated schema of how they are going to store the conversation between users so that the latency of retrieving the old conversation view should be as low as possible.
  As the data we are going to store is going to be at the scale of petabytes in a year, we need to consider the scaling of data also while storing it.

I have gone through the below links:
[https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/design-messenger/#*=*](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/design-messenger/#_=_)
I have also gone through the video released by fb where they talk about their latest implementation Iris.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eADBCKKf8PA

But i am unable to find the elaborated description of how they store the data pertaining to different users which enables them to retrieve the data so faster. Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Well Basically, you can use the Graph API to download data from their server and see the structure for yourself. And since this is the usual way any developer would learn about it, nobody described it :)
And it changes every 2-3 years :D